# Updating libstdc++ on mac

Tags: macos, libraries, llvm

When trying to compile the latest version of LLVM on Mac OS X 10.8.5 I get the following error/warning about libstdc++ version:

```
===
checking whether Clang will select a modern C++ standard library... no
configure: error:
We detected a missing feature in the standard C++ library that was known to be
missing in libstdc++4.6 and implemented in libstdc++4.7. There are numerous
C++11 problems with 4.6's library, and we don't support GCCs or libstdc++ older
than 4.7. You will need to update your system and ensure Clang uses the newer
standard library.


===
```

I can't find any clear info on how to update libstdc++. A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537605/how-do-i-update-libc-and-libstdc-on-os-x-10-5) that I found
 didn't help.

Would updating libstdc++ end up breaking lots of other things?

In case it's relevant, I have homebrew installed and would like to avoid macports.

Comment: macports to deal with this uses  libc++.

Comment: Sorry i don't follow. Are you suggesting to somehow use libc++?

Comment: yes - the [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) page says "Another problem with libstdc++ is that it is tightly integrated with G++ development, tending to be tied fairly closely to the matching version of G++." amongst other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i didn't need have to explore macports for working around this issue. Mac-OSX 10.8 already has libc++ installed and llvm can be asked to use libc++ instead of libstdc++ by using the `enable-libcpp` flag in the configure stage.

Comment: The configure stage? Are you building llvm from source then with a `./configure` command?